# Laravel5.5 using socialite login via Facebook Can't Load URL

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-login

I am using laravel5.5 with laravel/socialite.
Currently, I am developing my project on localhost:8000

I have setting everything in correct way, but when I try login via Facebook

I got this error message from Facebook:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

In facebook's app setting(Basic) I have setting

```
-->Domain APP 

localhost

-->Web Site

Site URL

http://localhost:8000
```

[facebook's app setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L648n.png)

If you can help me solve this problem I would be appreciated for your help

Comment: localhost for google is google :)

Comment: Try to add `127.0.0.1 my.app` to your `hosts` file then add it to google settings.

Comment: Can you please explain more in deep details. Thank again for your comment. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you insert your domain in App > Facebook Login > Settings >
Valid OAuth redirect URIs (input text)?
I occurred this problem when I forget to insert this field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the domain on the facebook developers settings, and enable the website to be live on App Review section.